# How do I secure my hls link so that no other site will use it?

Tags: nginx, http-live-streaming, rtmp, hls.js, nginx-rtmp

I made a streaming server using Nginx RTMP.

I created a live streaming server using Nginx, according to the explanation in this link: Create a secure adaptive bit-rate HLS stream with Nginx/RTMP/Ffmpeg on Ubuntu 20.04 (2021).

I streamed on the server and used the file extracted from the stream I mean this, for example: https://mydomain/hls/stream/index.m3u8

I put it in the video player on my site and it works fine.

The problem here is that anyone who uses the m3u8 file or link and puts it in a player on their site works.

I don't want that... I just want the broadcast to work on my website I've seen many sites use this method to protect broadcasts from being stolen from other sites

I want when I open this link: https://mydomain/hls/stream/index.m3u8 it doesn't work I only want it to work if I add it in the video player inside my site.

My question is: How do I make the m3u8 link work only on sites I own?

Comment: You can set a check on the `Referer` request header, but that isn't foolproof.  You can use DRM via Encrypted Media Extensions and withhold the keys for only users on your page, but even this can be worked around with some more effort.  You'll have to decide how much effort is worth it for your use case.

Comment: I have no problem putting in the effort as long as it teaches me something new. Please help me figure out how to do it